# Getting "error simple_form [not found]" with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, simple-form

I wanted to customize my devise views, so I used `rails g devise:views` command and got error (generator just skipped it and went further) `error  simple_form [not found]`

Ok, I went to Gemfile and added this gem called simple_form, ran `bundle install` and... got the same error while generating views

What's wrong?

Comment: have you restarted the rails server after running `bundle install`?

Comment: Or have you added this gem https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form to Gemfile and bundled it again?

Comment: why do I need to restart server for it? I've never restarted server after `bundle install` and it's never been a problem. And yes, I've added this gem, of course, as it was described in question

Comment: even when is valid that you should not restart rails, is possible that you need to restart spring. But I don't think that's your problem. Can you check if simple_form is BEFORE devise in Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

If you already added the `simple_form` gem to the Gemfile, try running `rails g simple_form:install` and then run again `rails g devise:views`.